# How to generate a referral link from an Hash code in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, sha

I have a system where **each account** of a user has a **unique id**, I can't user that id as a referral link because it contains dashes `-`.

I need to **generate** a **unique referral** code **given that id**, I thought about using a `sha256`  of that id.
The problem is that the `sha256` is too long to be used as a referral but if I truncate it, the collision chances increase.

Is there any way to generate a referral link given an id?

this is the format id: `04v23533-680d-1107-j4h1-1c32343c1004`

Comment: Why does the presence of dashes prevent you using it as a referral link?

Comment: I would like a standard referral link without dashes

Comment: What is non-standard about referral links with dashes? The first site with a referral system I could think of (Amazon) uses dashes in their referral links!

Comment: my bad then, I'm gonna change my mind on that, I would like at least to not have such long id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user IDs are random and unique, then you can't use them to generate shorter IDs without collisions (because you're effectively trying to compress random data).

Realistically though, are collisions a concern? If you have 500 users a a truncated hash has a one in 100 billion chance of colliding, is that really a problem? Depends how many users you have, and how long your codes can be.

But referral links don't need to be secret, they just need to be unique. So at the simplest level you could just generate sequential integers and use those for the IDs? Sure, you could guess other valid referral IDs, but who cares?

If you want them to be a bit more complex, you could generate random strings, and check them against the current list of IDs in the database to make sure that they're unique. But this might slow down once you have millions of users.